# MS Access Form locked for edit - Added unlock button but can't add New Record

Tags: ms-access, button, vba

I've got a MS Access form with a sub-form which I want to be read-only for existing records to prevent accidental changes. I've done this by putting simple code on both forms:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Me.AllowEdits = False
Me.AllowDeletions = False
Me.AllowAdditions = False
End Sub
```

I also added a button that changes the form to allow edits:

```
Private Sub Command110_Click()
Me.AllowEdits = True
Me.AllowDeletions = True
Me.AllowAdditions = True
End Sub
```

So I can then edit the form. However I have a button on the parent form to create a new record. I used the standard button function builder "Record Operations -> Add New Record" to create this button. But when I try to use it the error says: Error - You Can't Go To The Specified Record.

So I created a new button with this code:

```
Private Sub NewClientButton_Click()
Me.AllowEdits = True
Me.AllowDeletions = True
Me.AllowAdditions = True
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```

Thinking that would solve it but I still get an error: Runtime Error 2105 You can't Go To Specified Record.

The code on my form in totality looks like this:

```
Private Sub Command110_Click()
Me.AllowEdits = True
Me.AllowDeletions = True
Me.AllowAdditions = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
Me.AllowEdits = False
Me.AllowDeletions = False
Me.AllowAdditions = False
End Sub

Private Sub NewClientButton_Click()
Me.AllowEdits = True
Me.AllowDeletions = True
Me.AllowAdditions = True
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```

Is it just the ordering of my code subs that is the problem or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `Me.Recordset.AddNew` instead of the docmd

Comment: That suppresses the error but no new record is added - progress? :)

Comment: That's odd. You're calling this code on the subform, not the main form, right?

Comment: Actually it's being called on the main form. The last code paste is all from the main form.

Comment: Eh... Then all your code should use `Me.NameOfSubformControl.Form` instead of `Me`

Comment: OK but I might have some issues there as my subform already has:
`Private Sub Form_Current()
Me.AllowEdits = Me.Parent.AllowEdits
Me.AllowDeletions = Me.Parent.AllowDeletions
Me.AllowAdditions = Me.Parent.AllowAdditions
End Sub`

If I use your "nameofsubformcontrol" syntax maybe I don't need the subform code at all?

Comment: Well, you need to think about your design. If you're going to pull `AllowEdits` etc. from your parent form, you need to do that again as soon as you change it, they don't auto-synchronize, and you can't set them ByRef to a single value. I won't design your application for you.